# How to hide dropdown icon in react semantic ul

Tags: reactjs, frontend, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am going to use one of the dropdown menu options from react semantic ui, and I want to get rid of the dropdown icon.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const DropdownExamplePointing = () => (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>Home</Menu.Item>
    <Dropdown text='Shopping' pointing className='link item'>
      <Dropdown.Menu>
        <Dropdown.Header>Categories</Dropdown.Header>
        <Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown text='Clothing'>
            <Dropdown.Menu>
              <Dropdown.Header>Mens</Dropdown.Header>
              <Dropdown.Item>Shirts</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item>Pants</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item>Jeans</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item>Shoes</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Divider />
              <Dropdown.Header>Womens</Dropdown.Header>
              <Dropdown.Item>Dresses</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item>Shoes</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item>Bags</Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
          </Dropdown>
        </Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item>Home Goods</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item>Bedroom</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Divider />
        <Dropdown.Header>Order</Dropdown.Header>
        <Dropdown.Item>Status</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item>Cancellations</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
    <Menu.Item>Forums</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Contact Us</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
)

export default DropdownExamplePointing
```

[image]

Doc: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-pointing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by passing `icon` prop to Dropdown. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-forked-4d46lz?file=/index.js)

```
<Dropdown icon={null} text="Shopping" pointing className="link item">
```